# An alternative to dimethylsulfoxide (DMSO) for cryoprotection?

Tags: biochemistry

Is there an appropriate alternative to DMSO? I mean for embryo or oocyte freezing?

I am a PhD student at present. I am going to study this substance and I'm very interested in this field.

Comment: Hi, I took the liberty of modifying your question title to be more specific about what you're interested in DMSO for. I hope this is aligned with your intent.